# angular-ng-autocomplete: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Pipe')

Tags: angular

I try to make a ng-auto-complete inside my angular application, I use this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-autocomplete) for test, but I get this error when I start my application:

```
angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs?a001:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Pipe')
    at eval (angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs?a001:33:158)
    at Object../node_modules/angular-ng-autocomplete/fesm2015/angular-ng-autocomplete.mjs (vendor.bundle.js:822:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (manifest.bundle.js:713:30)
    at fn (manifest.bundle.js:118:20)
    at eval (shared.module.ts?dade:52:1)
    at Object../src/main/webapp/app/shared/shared.module.ts (main.bundle.js:1901:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (manifest.bundle.js:713:30)
    at fn (manifest.bundle.js:118:20)
    at eval (index.ts?0f7e:22:1)
    at Object../src/main/webapp/app/shared/index.ts (main.bundle.js:1545:1)
```

[code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-autocomplete):

```
         <div class="ng-autocomplete">
            <ng-autocomplete
                [data]="countries"
                [searchKeyword]="keyword"
                placeholder="Enter the Country Name"
                (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
                (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
                (inputFocused)='onFocused($event)'
                historyIdentifier="countries"
                [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
                [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
            </ng-autocomplete>
            
            <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
                <a [innerHTML]="item.name"></a>
            </ng-template>
            
            <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
                <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
            </ng-template>
        </div>
```

Comment: show your code as well kindly? Because the error is related to so Pipe maybe you have custom made etc?

Comment: @WahabShah see edit and example link

Comment: I dont see any link?

Comment: this one https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-autocomplete